# In the confirm method of spring integrated rabbitmq, ack is always false

Tags: spring, rabbitmq

spring 5.17

rabbitmq 2.18

junit 4.12

### problem

> When I test the `confirm` of reliable delivery of messages, I use `topic` mode to test. When I send a message to the switch, I call back `confirm(CorrelationData correlationData, boolean ack, String cause)`. Even if the `ack` is sent successfully, the`ack`is always false, and there are This message, consumers can also consume this message.

### code

producer

```
   <rabbitmq:queue id="spring_topic_queue01" name="spring_topic_queue01" auto-declare="true"/>
    <rabbitmq:queue id="spring_topic_queue02" name="spring_topic_queue02" auto-declare="true"/>
    <rabbitmq:topic-exchange name="spring_topic_exchange">
        <rabbitmq:bindings>
            <rabbitmq:binding pattern="*.java.#" queue="spring_topic_queue01"/>
            <rabbitmq:binding pattern="*.*.spring" queue="spring_topic_queue02"/>
            <rabbitmq:binding pattern="sql.#" queue="spring_topic_queue02"/>
        </rabbitmq:bindings>
    </rabbitmq:topic-exchange>
```

consumer

```
    <bean id="topicQueueListener01" class="com.zyl.TopicQueueListener01"/>
    <bean id="topicQueueListener02" class="com.zyl.TopicQueueListener02"/>
    
    <rabbitmq:listener-container connection-factory="connectionFactory">
    
        <rabbitmq:listener ref="topicQueueListener01" queue-names="spring_topic_queue01"/>
        <rabbitmq:listener ref="topicQueueListener02" queue-names="spring_topic_queue02"/>

    </rabbitmq:listener-container>
```

Listener

```
public class TopicQueueListener01 implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Consumer1："+new String(message.getBody()));
    }
}

public class TopicQueueListener02 implements MessageListener {
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        System.out.println("Consumer2："+new String(message.getBody()));
    }
}
```

Test

```
    @Test
    public void topicTest() throws InterruptedException {
  
        rabbitTemplate.setConfirmCallback((correlationData, ack, cause) -> {
            if (ack)
                System.out.println("ok!\n"+cause);
            else
                System.out.println("fail!\n"+cause);
        });

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend("spring_topic_exchange",
                "sql.ssm.out", "Hello RabbitMQ!");

        Thread.sleep(10);
    }
```

Output result

> Do not write `Thread.sleep(10);`
> `fail! clean channel shutdown; protocol method: #method\<channel.close\>(reply-code=200, reply-text=OK,class-id=0, method-id=0)`

> Add `Thread.sleep(10)`; the result is `ok! null`

What is the reason, under normal circumstances, there should be no need to write  `Thread.sleep(10);` `ack` should also be `true`